# Top answer poisoning

Tags: discussion, edits

Can't you create a great answer which receives a ton of upvotes.  Then later go in and change the answer to something completely wrong.  And even do so subtly so that it looks fine.  I don't think I have enough rep yet, but couldn't you also edit someone else's top answer and be even more malicious?

Does SO protect from this other than the Wiki-community method?  Does it matter?

Comment: dont worry, we will find you....

Comment: Something akin to Wikipedia vandalism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everybody can see the edit history, so you can't hide an edit. The community does a great job of policing itself in this way. Like in hockey. If you take a cheap shot, somebody's dropping the gloves and will call you out on it.

Tangentially, I cannot wait until October.

Comment: History, duh!

Comment: What's in October?

Comment: Halloween.

Comment: @mmyers: The return of awesome in all its glory: http://bruins.nhl.com/club/schedule.htm

Comment: @Eric: The return of awesome in all its glory? But football season starts next month...

Comment: @mmyers: Lord knows I love football, but hockey holds that special place in my heart.

Comment: I was going to come up with a witty comeback... but nothing quite does justice to the spectacle of a hockey-lover. :P

Comment: "they brought their F$%^ toys!"

Comment: Note that if an edit is made quick enough, there's no additional revision left for it - if the upvotes come fast enough one could edit it without leaving a trace.

Comment: @bodonlan: those votes'd have to come in pretty freaking fast. Go Wings

Answer (score 2):

When you edit anything, it's bumped to the top of the active view.  When you edit old questions, those edits tend to stand out in that view.  The odds are good someone will review it and correct it.

You *might* get away with it for a while if you do the edit very early on a Sunday morning before a holiday when few people are using the site.  But even then the revision history is available and if the item is important enough where many people actually view it someone will flag it for correction eventually.

So if you're so lame as to have nothing better to do for you holiday, you *might* get away with vandalizing questions that no one cares about any more.

Answer (score 1):

They have systems in place to guard against this, mainly flagging a post.

I'm good enough, I'm smart enough, and doggone it, people like me.